# How to show the image in full view

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I have an image and I need it to be shown with its full view as it is. But the image is shown in the phone after loading is reduced to fit the screen. how do I include the image in full size and resolution as it is so that it can be scrolled to see the width?

Here is my layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#EEEEEE">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:scrollbars="vertical" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="#77aa88">

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView   android:text="Xkcd"
        android:textColor="#6E7B91"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:textScaleX="1.8"

        android:id="@+id/TextHead" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

<TextView   android:text="A webcomic of romance, sarcasm, math, and language."
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textScaleX="1.1"
        android:id="@+id/TextSub" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView 
 android:scrollbars="horizontal" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/MainImage" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the matrix [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/mainimage" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mainimage"
            android:scaleType="matrix"/>
```

Comment: Thanks dude.Now I can scroll but only in vertical direction. Is there any way to use the horizontal too. In the above code I already used horizontal in scollbars, but doesnt happen. pls suggest

Comment: Try using fill_parent for the height in ScrollView. Experiment a bit with the heights in your layout.

Comment: can you pls tell why cant the imageview show a jpg image when downloaded from web. it works fine with png.

Comment: You need to use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(). See http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-display-jpg-in-sdcard-on.html